# What happens if fsck.ext4 -y is run on a ext3 fs and how to I recover from it

Tags: linux, raid, ext3, ext4, fsck

I had a mountable fs (pretty sure it was ext3), fsck.ext4 was run with -y and ended in a segmentation fault. Now it is unmountable (dmesg says it's corrupt) and identifies as a ext4 fs via the "blkid" command. The fs happens to sit on a raid 0 array mad up of 3 partitions.

As I am not 100% positive that is was originally ext3 I don't want to try running fsck.ext3. I also have no idea if that would work even if it was the case.

I would hope that fsck is intelligent enough to check the fs type and at least provide a warning.

Any suggestions on how to recover from this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just cut your losses and restore from backup.

Comment: There is no backup

Comment: Depending on your OS the fsck.ext* programs are all hard/soft links to the same binary so yes it aught to be smart enough to figure out the fs type, you'd have to read the source to confirm that though.

Comment: If there are no backups, then this was not a production server, correct?

Comment: It's in a research lab, still vital.

Comment: is it not an alias to fsck -T ext*?

Comment: It must not have been **that** vital. Count this as a lesson...

Comment: I did not design the system, I inherited it.

Comment: No backups is bad enough but RAID 0 as well is just this kind of disaster waiting to happen. I know a researcher who almost had their career wrecked before it began because their lab did (pretty much) exactly this. Fortunately they were able to gather together all the data they needed to complete their PhD and fortunately their lab learned from it and put in place the right backups etc.

Comment: Inheriting a system is *not* an excuse not to improve it, that's rather unprofessional behaviour.

Comment: Have you checked whether or not the real cause behind this problem is a failed disk on your raid 0?

Comment: The snarky criticisms here do not help in answering the question about `fsck`. The comment area should be used to "ask for more information or suggest improvements", not for wandering into meta-topics about the company's bad practices.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ ls -la /sbin/fsck.ext?
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 jun 24  2013 /sbin/fsck.ext2 -> e2fsck
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 jun 24  2013 /sbin/fsck.ext3 -> e2fsck
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 jun 24  2013 /sbin/fsck.ext4 -> e2fsck
```

So the fsck you ran is the correct one. If your filesystem is now so corrupt it won't mount you have two options:

- Restore from backup
- Pay a lot of money to a data recovery company.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is still corrupt as fsck (version 2.19) segfaults. I am currently trying fsck (version 2.24) as some google results suggested segfaults weren't uncommon in older versions.

Comment: @The_Pacifist What OS distribution and version is this?

Comment: The fsck.ext4 was run on a liveboot archlinux with version 2.19 of fschk, it was an older version of archlinux 3.6ish kernel. The newest run with fsck 2.24 is being run on the most recent archlinux liveboot. fsck.ext? has independent binaries.

Comment: Arch Linux, no backup, RAID 0. Are you sure this isn't a home system? It sounds like the opposite of everything you want in a professional environment.

Comment: Archlinux liveboot, ubuntu 10.04 native.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably software RAID, but assuming you can see the block device, my recommendation for data recovery on ext2/3/4, XFS and other Linux filesystem is [**UFS Explorer**](http://www.ufsexplorer.com). It's commercial software, but relatively inexpensive.

Seeing as `blkid` returns the right filesystem type, running a UFS Explorer scan against the device (and redirected to another disk) may be a clean approach to seeing what's recoverable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Update: So those curious the last fsck (version 2.24) was able to complete. All of the resulting data was in (lost+found). I am currently backing up this directory before extracting anything. At first glance though, the majority of the data does seem to be there. So it's just a matter of traversing inodes instead of directory trees.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: on redhat 6 the fsck.ext? aren't link " ls -la /sbin/fsck.ext?
-rwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 190344 Jun 25  2013 /sbin/fsck.ext2
-rwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 190344 Jun 25  2013 /sbin/fsck.ext3
-rwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 190344 Jun 25  2013 /sbin/fsck.ext4
"

Comment: I hope you will be able to recover at least some of the data. When you are done with this crisis, schedule some time with your manager or the stakeholders and propose a plan to fix this system that you inherited. Make sure you are able to schedule time and resources to get the system to a point where it can be properly backed up and restored. While this may not be easy, it is the management's responsibility to see that you have the time and resources required to do the job properly.

Comment: @c4f4t0r: They are hard links. The 5 after the r-x is the link count. The binaries are all the same size, they are the same binary.

Comment: @Iain yes that true :)

Comment: For the record I don't have a manager. I am a graduate student trying to graduate and play sysadmin. I know it's not the best scenario and there were bound to be mistakes/bad designs both inherited and designed. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: don't forget to mount the filesystem read-only (`ro` flag) while you are trying to recover any files. The less you write to it, the higher the chances you can recover your files.